# Graphs of (un)bounded color valence

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, coloring

Talking about colored graphs there is a definition given for graphs with *bounded color valence*. This definition is as follows:

> A vertex-colored graph $G=(V,E)$ has bounded color valence, if there is a constant $D$, such that for every color class $C$ every vertex $v$ (possibly in $C$) has at most $D$ neighbors or at most $D$ non-neighbors in $C$.

It's hard for me understanding this definition. I can't think of an example for a graph that doesn't have bounded color valence, as e.g. one can assign a different color for every vertex.

Link to the definition: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0142v2.pdf (p. 16)

Comment: A better way of phrasing this might be "the color valences of all vertices of the graph are bounded by $d$, where the color valence of a vertex is ..."

Comment: Consider the disjoint union of graphs $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$, $\dots$

Comment: Wait, is it possible for your graphs to be infinite? My previous statement is false in that case.

Comment: If the graph is finite it obviously satisfies the condition for any $d$ larger than the cromattic number.

Comment: @Penitent I changed the definition to the one originally given in the paper.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez I actually don't think it does make any difference. Just the number of colors get arbitrarily large with the method i mentioned.

Comment: Does it mean a given colouring has this property, though, or that all such colourings have this property? If the first, then it seems straightforward; if the latter, then I cannot think of such a graph. Or does it require a bound on the number of colours?

Comment: @Penitent A given vertex-coloring has the property to be a bounded color valence one if the mentioned requirements are given. I edited the original post with the link.